# How to remove all Instances of Froala editor?

Tags: reactjs, froala

I'm new to the froala editor. And I'm finding a way to destroy all the previous instances generated for the froala editor.

**My requirement**: Is there any way to destroy all the froala editor instance?

Hope anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a record of all froala instances and remove them with destroy function. Please check this [link](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events#destroy)  and this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0d1enoah)

```
editor.destroy();
```

It might be helpful to you.

Comment: I knew how to destroy it, but I need a way to remove all instances without keeping track of the instance as I'm using the class to create multiple instances dynamically. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize Froala

```
var editor = new FroalaEditor('.class')
```

Destroy all instances

```
for (let i = 0; i < editor.length; i++) {
  editor[i].destroy();
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sherbsherb/y5j8pnce/